# Mixing 'Like' with comparators in an iif statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to use the query builder to formulate a query based on user input on a form, but I'm running into an issue.

I've been using this code to filter and check for null/"ALL" field before which is working fine.

```
Like IIf([Forms]![TransactionsForm]![ComboActStatus]="ALL","*",
[Forms]![TransactionsForm]![ComboActStatus])
```

But I run into an issue when I want to do the same thing with fields that signify a range. I attempted this:

```
IIf([forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountFrom] Is Null Or 
[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo] Is Null,
([dbo_customerQuery].[amount]) Like "*",
([dbo_customerQuery].[amount])>=[forms]! [TransactionsForm]![txtAmountFrom] And
([dbo_customerQuery].[amount])<=[Forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo])
```

But it's causing my entire query to fail. How can I do this similar thing? Use "Like *" in the null case (return everything), but use comparators rather than "like" statements in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that finally worked for me, and didn't have Access split it into separate lines was:

```
>=IIf([forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountFrom] Is Null,0,[forms]![TransactionsForm]!
[txtAmountFrom]) And <=IIf([forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo] Is Null,9999999999,
[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something `LIKE "*"` will return `true` for all values, so this should work:

```
IIf([forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountFrom] Is Null Or 
    [forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo] Is Null,
true,
([dbo_customerQuery].[amount])>=[forms]! [TransactionsForm]![txtAmountFrom] And
[dbo_customerQuery].[amount])<=[Forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtAmountTo])
)
```

Comment: Im doing this inside a criteria in query designer, not a where statement. So what do I put before the iif statement? Anything? Or is that how it starts? Since this still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you put in 1=1 or some other criteria that will always be true?

Comment: I mean wouldn't this version be saying that I only want ones that are equal to "true" or something? I know like "*" will return everything, but I don't know how to do a date range using a like clause

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you can't use `true`, but you could use >= '01-01-0001' or something like that to get all records.

Comment: ^That sounds like an interesting solution. My question is will that slow the query down to have to do that comparison multiple times?

Comment: I also saw an interesting suggestion on another forum "WHERE
   (YourDateField >= [Enter Start Date] OR [Enter Start Date] IS NULL)
   AND
   (YourDateField <= [Enter End Date] OR [Enter End Date] IS NULL)"      It sounds pretty good but for some reason Access continues to split the criteria up into like four lines using the ors, rather than keeping it on one - which isnt really feasible when I add more criteria.

Comment: No more than a `like` would.

Comment: I would also suggest learning how to write SQL rather than relying on Access's interactive builder.  It's fine for basic queries but can easily become ineffective.